# ¿Cómo puedo guardar cookies para alternar entre el modo oscuro/claro?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy usando javascript en mi sitio web para cambiar entre el modo normal y oscuro y funciona muy bien, el problema es que al momento de recargar la página este vuelve al modo normal en caso de que el usuario haya elegido el modo oscuro. Quisiera saber si hay una forma de guardar el modo que el usuario elija al momento de recargar la página.

```
 const body = document.querySelector('body'),
      sidebar = body.querySelector('nav'),
      toggle = body.querySelector(".toggle"),
      searchBtn = body.querySelector(".search-box"),
      modeSwitch = body.querySelector(".toggle-switch"),
      modeText = body.querySelector(".mode-text");


toggle.addEventListener("click" , () =>{
    sidebar.classList.toggle("close");
})

searchBtn.addEventListener("click" , () =>{
    sidebar.classList.remove("close");
})

modeSwitch.addEventListener("click" , () =>{
    body.classList.toggle("dark");
    
    if(body.classList.contains("dark")){
        modeText.innerText = "Modo noche";
    }else{
        modeText.innerText = "Modo día";
        
    }
});
```

Comment: Sí, usando [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) o [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) que permiten el almacenamiento de claves=>valores que luego puedes recuperar cuando quieras mientras no cierres la sesión o el navegador (son datos guardados solo en el navegador). Pruébalo y si te dan problemas puedes [edit] la pregunta y agregar lo que has intentado y el error que tienes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listo, usé localStorage como solución. A continuación anexo el código de cómo me quedó.

```
let getMode = localStorage.getItem("mode");
      if (getMode && getMode === "dark") {
        body.classList.add("dark");
        modeSwitch.classList.add("active");
      }

      modeSwitch.addEventListener("click", () => {
        body.classList.toggle("dark");

        if (!body.classList.contains("dark")) {
          modeText.innerText = "Modo noche";
          return localStorage.setItem("mode", "light");
        }
        else{
        modeText.innerText = "Modo día";
        
        localStorage.setItem("mode", "dark");
        }
      });

      modeSwitch.addEventListener("click", () => modeSwitch.classList.toggle("active"));
```